# HiQPDF error "Cannot write the document to output file. Invalid Serial Number Version." when merging 2 pdf

Tags: pdf-generation, hiqpdf

I'm using HiQPdf to merge 2 pdf in one file, following to the official help: https://www.hiqpdf.com/documentation/html/e5d2f1ee-dccb-4351-888e-e3f3c15a93a5.htm
I get the "HiQPdf Evaluation". Which prove the code works.
I added my serial number:

```
PdfDocument resultDocument = new PdfDocument();
resultDocument.SerialNumber = "AU***************-OA=="; // this line is not in the help
PdfDocument document1 = PdfDocument.FromFile("c:\\temp\\doc1.pdf);
resultDocument.AddDocument(document1);
PdfDocument document2 = PdfDocument.FromFile("c:\\temp\\doc2.pdf);
resultDocument.AddDocument(document2);
resultDocument.WriteToFile("c:\\temp\\MergePdf.pdf"); //getting an Exception here !
```

I get an exception on the *resultDocument.WriteToFile* : *Cannot write the document to output file. Invalid Serial Number Version.*
If I remove the *resultDocument.SerialNumber*, the merged pdf is generated but with the "HiQPdf Evaluation" water mark.

I assert that my serial is correct since I succesfully use it to for HtmlToPdf conversion:

```
HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();
htmlToPdfConverter.SerialNumber = "AU***************-OA==";
PdfDocument resultDoc = null;
resultDoc = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlToPdfDocument(html, "");
```

This code (with my serial) succesfully produces a PDF without the "HiQPdf Evaluation: water mark. And if I remove my serial, the "HiQPdf Evaluation: water mark appears.

Is there another place/way to use the serial? Is it possible that my Serial is correct for htmlToPdfConverter but not the PdfDocument merging?

Comment: Thanks @KJ, I tried with eval serial number and it woks (I mean I don't get exception, but of course the "HiQPdf Evaluation" water mark is added to the merged PDF). I already sent a mail to the support.

Answer (score 1):

I finally received a response from the support: my serial is valid for a PREVIOUS version of HiQPdf.

Be aware that in Nuget, the only version available is version 12. To downgrade you need to find a backup of your previous version of HiQPdf.dll and put it manually in you packages.

> Below the response from the support:
>
> HiQPdf Sales sales@hiqpdf.com Mon 18/04/2022 18:20
>
> Hello,
>
> Your serial number is for version 10 of the software. For version 12
> you need a new serial number.
>
> You can renew the old license with a 20% renewal discount to obtain a
> serial number for the latest version of the software in the page
> below: [link removed]
>
> Best Regards,
>
> Jacob